# problemas en usar PDFuim en Delphi

Tags: pdf, delphi

Estoy tratando de usar la PDFium en Delphi Rio 10.3.3, lo agregue a mi library path para no tener que agregarlo a casa proyecto en el que desee usarlo, pero por alguna razon me genera el sgte error:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Verifique las dll y demas que proveen en el repositorio del proyecto e hice numerosas pruebas.

solo cuando lo agrego al proyecto funciona correctamente
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

estoy omitiendo algo para que funcione de la forma en la que necesito?

Comment: El "no funciona de esa forma" es poco descriptivo y con esa informqación es difícil saber qué puede estar pasando. Si el paquete está instalado correctamente y los directorios añadidos correctamente debería funcionar sin problemas y sin tener que añadir nada en cada proyecto. Debería añadir los errores que obtienes y las configuraciones que tienes (puedes editar la pregunta).

Comment: Editaré la pregunta la para agregar mas detalles, muchas gracias.

Comment: Posiblemente esté usando una versión de la DLL que no incluye la función del error. Haz una búsqueda en el PC por la DLL que habrá una versión antigua que aparece antes en el PATH de Windows. Orden de búsqueda de DLL: https://learn.microsoft.com/es-es/windows/win32/dlls/dynamic-link-library-search-order#standard-search-order-for-desktop-applications

Answer (score 0):

Al realizar la instalación de la librería, ya se añaden (o se deberían añadir) a la configuración de Delphi los path necesarios.

En mi caso, por ejemplo, me añade el siguiente, al `Library Path` de la configuración de `Language/Delphi/Library`:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Winsoft\PDFium Component Suite\Delphi11
```

En otras versiones, la carpeta será diferente.

Si este path es correcto, no necesitas añadir nada más en la configuración de los proyectos para que funciones correctamente.
Al ejecutarlos sí que deberás tener la ***DLL en el mismo directorio del ejecutable, o en una carpeta incluida en el path*** para qu te la encuntre.